# Click event inside of Modal: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to figure out why my click test event is not working. I applied the same setup for another click event on the same file and it worked.
Using Jest and Enzyme for react js
Goal : click event able to capture the node and test to pass

This is what i have for my test case so far:

Test.js

```
 describe("Test Modal Components and Events ", () => {
let mountingDiv;
let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}  initialEntries={["/add"]} ><Policies {...baseProps} /></MemoryRouter>);
mountingDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(mountingDiv);
})
```

test case

```
it('Test click event on Close - Modal', () => {
 ReactModal.setAppElement('body');
 wrapper = mount( <ReactModal isOpen></ReactModal>,
  {attachTo: mountingDiv}
 );
 wrapper.setState({
    quickFilterModalOpen: false,
 })
 wrapper.update()
 expect(!!document.body.querySelector('.fullmodal')).toEqual(true);
 expect(!!document.body.querySelector('.sidemodal_addnew_x')).toEqual(true)
 document.querySelector("#closemodal-id").click();
});
```

Here is file.js

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.quickFilterModalOpen} style={descriptionModalStyle}>
  <div>
    <div className='fullmodal'>
    <div className='sidemodal_addnew_x' id="closemodal-id" onClick={this.closeModal}>
```

Comment: try to do console.log on document.querySelector("#closemodal-id") in your test case and see if it returns you anything.

Comment: returns null when i do console.log(document.querySelector("#closemodal-id"))

Comment: that's your issue then, because you cant call .click on a null value

Comment: Correct, not really sure how to approach this, i used the same method for another click event inside of modal and it worked fne

Comment: I would say try rendering it in the browser and then see if the same code works for you i.e. querySelector returns your Node or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modal should be visible for the close button to be clicked. Set `quickFilterModalOpen` to true and use `.find(selector)` to find the element to be clicked. (https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html)

```
    wrapper.setState({
        quickFilterModalOpen: true,
    })
    wrapper.update()
    wrapper.find("#closemodal-id").simulate("click");
```

Comment: i always use wrapper.find. Not able to use when it comes to Modal. So took me quiet some time to figure out the code above

Comment: Try using `shallow`, and set `quickFilterModalOpen` to true and maybe you can find the element inside the wrapper.

Comment: Is it possible to use shallow when you export default withRouter(file). ?

Answer (score -1):

I think that is a binding issue, i will go for the event listener or otherwise go for an approach like 
onClick = {this.closeModal.bind(this)} or similar, it depends on your code
Hope it helps

Comment: not an issue with binding rather issue is with rendering component